# How to fix CSOM Error: The type of data at position X is different than the one expected?

Tags: c#, csom

Im trying to get the resource's StatusAssginments using CSOM, including the field History, but it keeps giving me the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type of data at position 5621 is different than the one expected.

Here is the code:

```
internal static List<StatusAssignment> RetrieveAssignments(ProjectContext context, string emailUsuario)
{
    List<StatusAssignment> result = new List<StatusAssignment>();
    var resources = context.LoadQuery(context.EnterpriseResources);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    resources = resources.Where(i => i.Email == emailUsuario);

    foreach (var resource in resources)
    {
        var assignments = context.LoadQuery(resource.Assignments
                                                      .IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
                                                        assn => assn.Task,
                                                        assn => assn.Project,
                                                        assn => assn.Resource.Name,
                                                        assn => assn.History
                                                      ));
        context.ExecuteQuery(); // exception here

        result.AddRange(assignments);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Without the line `assn => assn.History`, the code works just fine, but I need the information inside that History field.

I've already tried updating the dll I use, also tried geting the StatusAssignments first, then getting the History one by one, and googled it but didn't find anyone with the same problem.
My user is set as Admin of the SPsite and Project site, and have all permissions, the app also has all permissions.